# Are there any open source Java analysis libraries for data/control dependence?

Tags: java, static-analysis

I am looking for a library/API that has some out of the box data and control dependence analyses for Java programs. This would be a static analysis on the control flow graph (CFG) of the given program to compute data dependences and control dependences. I would like to avoid reimplementing these techniques/algorithms if they have already been done. An inter-procedural analysis would be great, but I could work with a library that does an intra-procedural one as well.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** One thing I have found is [jChord](http://pag.cc.gatech.edu/chord/), but I haven't been able to determine yet if it actually has any of the out of the box functionality that I am looking for or if I would have to implement it myself.

Another possibility is the *[joeq](http://joeq.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html)* library which seems to at least have the infrastructure necessary for doing this, but the documentation (or lack thereof) is making it difficult for me to tell what it is actually capable of.

I am sure Eclipse does plenty of data flow analysis underneath the hood, but I haven't seen anything yet that is public facing. Anyone know of the Eclipse API having stuff like this?

Comment: I prefer open source, but I would at least be interested in hearing about other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/

Answer (score 2):

OP says he is interested in non-open source systems too.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [Java Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/JavaFrontEnd.html) can parse Java source code in all dialects 1.4-1.7, producing full ASTs, build symbol tables, compute types of expressions, and determine control and dataflows within methods, including explicity control dependence as requested by OP.

Usually folks that are interested in advanced analyses have something other than the raw analysis in mind.  DMS is an ecosystem of program analysis and transformation tools, that can be used to leverage such analyses into diagnostics about the existing code in terms of source location (drawn directly from the ASTs) or source code (prettyprinted from a subtree of interest), or to generate new code fragments (by assembling ASTs and prettyprinting them) or finally by actually changing the original code (by modifying the ASTs using procedural modifications or better yet, source-to-source transformation, and prettyprinting the modified AST).